# "More drunk" or "drunker"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, past-participles, comparatives

I am at a party. I drink wine till I'm drunk. Then I drink some more. So am I more drunk now, or drunker?

Comment: Considering that *drunk* is a past participle, I would say *more drunk.*  Why? for the same reason that I say *he was beaten more* and not *he was beatener.*

Comment: Hmm... care to turn that into an answer?

Comment: @JimThio Why do you want wrong answers?

Comment: Is that wrong? Because I feel more drunk is correct. I don't know. Drunker sounds like the guy that drink. Is the fact that drunk is a past participle means anything?

Answer (score 6):

[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives) states that:

> Adjectives make their comparative and superlative forms in different ways, depending on the base adjective itself.

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drunk), the comparative form of drunk is 'drunker', and the superlative form being 'drunkest'.

If the adjective were to have three syllables or more, then you would then use 'more', and 'most'.

[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives)  uses the following example:

> interesting---> more interesting---> most interesting
>   attractive---> more attractive---> most attractive

So to answer your question, I would say, "I am now *drunker*, than before."

Comment: But you wouldn't want a comma there.

Answer (score 0):

In UK English usage the sentence could be either:

1 Now I am more drunk than I was earlier

2 Now I am drunker than I was earlier

Without any qualification the sentence sounds incomplete. I think a better construction for the sentence could be something like 'I'm more drunk than before, now' or 'I'm drunker than before, now'.